# TransactionScope giving error Distributed transaction completed. Either enlist this session in a new transaction or the NULL transaction

Tags: c#, transactionscope

I am writing a Class library in c# to perform Archiving functions for production database (using SQLServer 2000). In the function, I am moving records from production database to Archive database for multiple tables and using transactionScope to rollback the changes if something fails.

Since large data is being moved from production database to Archive database, it is taking at least 1/2 hr. If I remove transactionScope, everything works fine but with transactionScope, I get below error after 9-10 minutes.

**Distributed transaction completed. Either enlist this session in a new transaction or the NULL transaction.**

below is pseudo code

```
using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0)))
{
    Open connection
    Check data present in production DB

Insert into Archivedb.dbo.table1(field1,field2,field3....) Select * from Proddb.dbo.table1 where date between date1 and date2
Insert into Archivedb.dbo.table2(field1,field2,field3....) Select * from Proddb.dbo.table2 where date between date1 and date2
Insert into Archivedb.dbo.table3(field1,field2,field3....) Select * from Proddb.dbo.table3 where date between date1 and date2
Insert into Archivedb.dbo.table4(field1,field2,field3....) Select * from Proddb.dbo.table4 where date between date1 and date2
}
```

Do I need to set timeout somewhere ?

### **EDIT**

Found the solution in below link after breaking my head for so long
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnetinterop/archive/2005/12/16/504604.aspx
Hope it will help others too.

Comment: did not find any solution still... Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: A proper solution would probably be to do a EnlistTransaction(null) when you hit an exception.

Comment: 403 :( This is why you should not only add a link to the solution.